# Multiple relations between one Dimension table and one Fact table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have only recently been learning Power BI and now I tried to make a star model (1 fact table and 1 dimension table), since that is recommended.

My practice data contains the following.

**Dimension table:**
Company name,
Company ID,
Company manager

**Fact table:**
Selling company ID,
Buying company ID,
Date,
Price

I thought i would set up relations between 'Company ID' and 'Selling company ID' and between 'Company ID' and 'Buying company ID'. The 'Company ID' in the Dimension table is unique and the ID's in the Fact table are not. So i wanted to make 1:many relationships from Dimension to Fact table.

I believed this would give me the possibility to see which company sold which product to which company. But Power BI does not allow me to make multiple active relationships between those two tables.

Did I model my data wrong or is there a solution? Should I make a second Dimension table? One for buyers, one for sellers?

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple relationships between a Fact and a Dimension then these are called role-playing dimensions.

The cleanest solution in this circumstance is normally to create a View of the Dimension for each role.

You could create a View for only one role and join directly to the table dimension for the other role but that is less easy to understand and, given that there is minimal overhead in creating Views, I would normally create a View per role

Answer (score 0):

Only one active relationship can be existing between two tables. There are some ways to work with multiple relationships but its a bit complicated.
However you can modelate your fact table in order to solve this problem using the following dax code:

```
Company Fac Table = 
VAR __buyingTable = FILTER( 'Fact Table', NOT( ISBLANK( 'Fact Table'[Buying company ID] ) ) )
VAR __sellingTable = FILTER( 'Fact Table', NOT( ISBLANK( 'Fact Table'[Selling company ID] ) ) )
Return
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        __buyingTable,
        "Company ID", 'Fact Table'[Buying company ID],
        "Date", 'Fact Table'[Date],
        "Price", 'Fact Table'[Price], 
        "Company type", "Buying Company"
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        __sellingTable,
        "Company ID", 'Fact Table'[Selling company ID],
        "Date", 'Fact Table'[Date],
        "Price", 'Fact Table'[Price], 
        "Company type", "Selling Company"
    )
)
```

The idea is to create a large table having only **1 Company ID** and a column **Company Type** to difference betweewn both selling and buying company.

So your final model would be something like this:

[image]

You can achieve this using power query but this is the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Do I understand correctly that each transaction then would become 2 rows? One for the seller and one for the buyer?

Comment: No, there would be only 1 row for each transaction.

Comment: How is that? You say that there will only be 1 Company ID and a column Company Type. 
Each transaction involves 2 companies ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

you can create inactive relations between then and then use USERELATIONSHIP function to activate the inactive relationships while performing the calculation. Note - when you are using inactive relations you need to create the calculations again using USERELATION function.